# Multiple translateX in Javascript (Webkit)

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, webkit

If I apply a `.style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(10px)';` on an element and then I would like to add another `.style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(10px)';` to reach a total of **20px** is impossible.

The element will again be **10px**.
How can I go around this?

(Except keeping the previous values and adding it to `translateX like = preValue+current+'px';`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already figured out out the answer.

```
var pixels = parseFloat(element.style.webkitTransform.split(/[()]/)[1]);
pixels += 10;
element.style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(' + pixels + 'px)';
```